# MySQL syntax error when using prepared statement with CONCAT

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement, variable-assignment, do-while

I'm trying to use a prepared statement within a stored procedure. I'm getting the syntax error in the initial `SET @idToUpdateQuery`. I already know that the `CONCAT` without the variable assignment using `:=` works correctly, as it's used elsewhere and works as intended. Essentially, I just need to be able to get the result of the prepared SELECT statement into the variable `@resultId`. The problematic code is as follows:

```
SET @distinctTableXIds = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tempTableX);

 SET @i = 0;
 WHILE @i < @distinctTableXIds DO

    /*CONCAT IS NEEDED HERE TO PASS USER DEFINED @i*/
    SET @idToUpdateQuery = CONCAT('SELECT @result := MAX(id) 
    FROM tableY 
    WHERE tableZId = (SELECT id FROM tempTableX ORDER BY id LIMIT ', @i, ', 1)');

    PREPARE @IdToUpdateStmt FROM @IdToUpdateQuery;
    EXECUTE @IdToUpdateStmt;

    SET @resultId = SELECT @result;

    UPDATE tableY
    SET someBoolean = 1
    WHERE id = @resultId;

    SET @i = @i + 1;

 END WHILE;
```

Comment: There is no syntax error in `SET @idToUpdateQuery = CONCAT(..);`. But `PREPARE @IdToUpdateStmt FROM @IdToUpdateQuery;` doesnt look correct. Try without `@`.

Comment: After staring at this for at least an hour, i JUST came to the same conclusion before refreshing this page. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use the `@` sigil for a statement name. It's not a user variable.

See example at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

```
mysql> PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'SELECT SQRT(POW(?,2) + POW(?,2)) AS hypotenuse';
mysql> SET @a = 3;
mysql> SET @b = 4;
mysql> EXECUTE stmt1 USING @a, @b;
```

Besides that, I don't think you need a prepared statement for this task at all. I can think of at least two other solutions. Give me a few minutes and I'll write one up.

---

One solution using a cursor (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html):

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE max_id INT;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT MAX(id) FROM tableY JOIN tempTableX ON (tableY.tableZId = temptableX.id) GROUP BY tableZId;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur1;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO max_id
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    UPDATE tableY SET someBoolean = 1 WHERE id = max_id;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur2;
END
```

---

Another solution that does it all in one UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE tableY AS y1
INNER JOIN tempTableX AS x ON (y1.tableZId = x.id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableY AS y2 ON (y1.tableZId = y2.tableZId AND y1.id < y2.id)
SET y1.someBoolean = 1
WHERE y2.id IS NULL;
```

The outer join trick is a way to find the row of y1 for which no row exists with the same `tableZId` and a greater `id`. In other words, it finds the largest `id` for each group of rows with a given `tableZId`.

Comment: sure, i'd like to see an alternative solution

Comment: nice. i'll tinker around with the UPDATE statement

Comment: Note I have not tested it! Please do not test it on your real data. :-)